# C language printf function and output problem

Tags: c, printf, bit-shift, integer-promotion

I need help solving this problem in my mind, so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

```
signed char c=0x10;
printf("%x", c<<0x4|c>>0x4);
```

Why output is 101?

Comment: Do you understand what the `<<`, `|`, and `>>` operators do?

Comment: Yes, I understand

Comment: So how does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: Then what do you expect as output?

Comment: I expected the result to be 1

Comment: First of all convert the number `0x10` to *binary* form. Then do the separate operations one by one on paper, using only binary numbers. Once you have a result, convert the binary number back to hexadecimal. And remember the *operator precedence* of the involved operators (shift highest, or lowest).

Comment: Why would you expect that... Ah, `char`. However, for the duration of the calculation, the numbers are promoted to `int`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Comment: Oh yes, the implicit integer promotion, don't forget that.

Comment: Basically: never do any form of bitwise arithmetic on signed integer types. And for that reason, also avoid bitwise arithmetic on small integer types which may get implicitly promoted.

Answer (score 5):

In expressions with shift operators the integer promotions are applied to the each operand and in this particular case to the object `c`.

From the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
> type of the result is that of the promoted left operand....

So after the integer promotions it will be represented like (provided that `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4`)

```
00000010
```

This expression

```
c<<0x4
```

produces the following value

```
00000100
```

and this expression

```
c>>0x4
```

produces the following value

```
00000001
```

The bitwise operator | yields

```
00000100
|
00000001
========
00000101
```

The result is outputted without leading zeroes as

```
101
```

That is the function printf outputs the resulted value of the type int as an object of the type unsigned int because the resulted value can be represented in an object of the type unsigned int.

To get the expected by you result use the length modifier `hh` as for example

```
printf("%#hhx", c<<0x4|c>>0x4);
```

In this case the program output will be

```
0x1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
signed char c=0x10;
printf("%x", c<<0x4|c>>0x4);
```

Why output is 101?

Because `c<<4==0x100` and `c>>4==0x01`.
ORing them together results in `0x101`

Important here is that there is implicit type promotion to `int` before applying the `<<` operator.

If you expected to get the nibbles swapped, you need to add some masking:

`(c&0x0F)<<4 | (c&0xF0)>>4`

Comment: How is c<<4==0x100 ?

Comment: @SrdjanPesevic Because the `signed char` values are [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int`. `c << 4` is essentially equivalent to `((int) c) << 4`.

Answer (score 1):

In most expressions, a `signed char` is automatically promoted to an `int`, which is at least 16 bits. So `c<<0x4` is evaluated with at least 16 bits of data; it does not lose the high bits as it would if the result were limited to eight bits.

So `c << 0x4` shifts 0001 0000 by four bits, producing 0001 0000 0000. And `c >> 0x4` of course produces 0001. ORing those together produces 0001 0000 0001, which is 101<sub>16</sub>.

You can remove the high bits in various ways. One is to explicitly convert the subexpression to the desired type: `(signed char) (c << 0x4) | c >> 0x4`. Note this has a problem in that the conversion of an out-of-range value to a signed type is implementation-defined. It is usually preferable to use unsigned types when working with bits in this way, as then the results are fully defined by the C standard.

Another method is to use AND with a “mask” to select the desired bits: `(c << 0x4 | c >> 0x4) & 0xFF`.